# How to use the Concurrency check attribute in Code first?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have been following the tutorial but I can't seem to make it work.

I have my model:

```
public int id { get; set; }

[Required]
[Index]
[Display(Name="First Name")]

public string firstname { get; set; }


[Required]
[Display(Name="Last Name")]
[ConcurrencyCheck]
public string lastname { get; set; }


[Required]
[Display(Name="Address")]
public string address { get; set; }
```

I also have everything working before I put the `ConcurrencyCheck` attribute.

Here is the update snippet:

```
CarlCtx ctx = new CarlCtx();
ctx.Entry(entry).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

But I get the exception right away even If I am the only user who is editing.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your concurrency token?

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application